# How java server client programing works with browser

Tags: java, web-services, server, glassfish, client

I just started to learn about java server programing and I was wondering - I know that there is a Java server program code, and I tried it with GlassFish through the GlassFish port, and it worked.

Now- where exactly do I need to insert the client code? I want for example to write a web app that gets a num and double it but if I have a server code that I can access to via url with port, what more do  need?

Does the browser *is* the client in that case? If so, does web application doesn't have Java client code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in a general sense the browser is the client. If you want this to be accessible on a browser, you will need to add an html and/or javascript document (the actual client code) to communicate with the java server.

Browsers don't generally support Java applets anymore due to security issues, so writing a Java client to be displayed in the browser is not a great way to go about it. Web app clients are written pretty much exclusively in html/javascript, but you could also write a standalone Java application (not in the browser) to communicate with the server using [java.net.HttpRequest](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html).

Comment: Yeah, That's what I thought. so the `ServerSocket` Object is unneccery in web apps? and what about threads - can I use them with html java web server?

Comment: You do still need an object like `ServerSocket` to listen for requests made to the server and respond to them. `ServerSocket` is useful for low-level communications between the server and client. If you want a higher-level, more abstracted API you could use [`HttpServer`](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-have-a-simple-http-server.html).

Comment: I don't see why not :) Just keep in mind that the client will usually be expecting a response.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a tutorial to get used to Glassfish/Servlets/etc, you could start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnadr/index.html) for example.

**The Browser is the client. Glassfish or any other Applicationserver is the server.**